# treeview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I want to use a treeview control in my asp.net project and when i drag and drop anything, it should update database. and there should be sort, when I change the sort when I drag and drop, the order column should be changed at the database.

(It is clear that treeview will get the items from database.)

Comment: Great i like it... but what's the problem?

Comment: how can i do it? :) I am waiting your answer..

Answer (score 0):

I would search for examples of this via google to see what options are available with the standard .NET components, and 3rd party components (commercially purchased and jquery style plugins) See which one best fits your need and have a go at implemneting what you need. If you have further problems, let us know.

Comment: yes i google this item and i found some 3rd party components. I have been researching free way :) and I want to improve myself while studying code

Comment: thank you, I have found it. 
Can you suggest any 3rd party component to me?
it should save order information also